# $timeout is not a function angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am beginner with angular js and I am trying to implement modal with hyperlink, I ham referring to this plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/M7qfegYIOqOQekoxLaj5?p=preview

I have been able to successfully open modal on hyperlink, but i am not able to display the data returned from function, it always gives error, $timeout is not a function, I am passing an additional parameter as well from ng-click.

```
    <td ng-repeat="column in columns">
        <div class="animate-switch" ng-if="column == spaceIdHeaderName">
         <a href="" ng-click="open(user[column])"> {{user[column]}} </a></div>
         <div class="animate-switch" ng-if="column != spaceIdHeaderName">{{user[column]}}</div>

   </td>
```

My Modal js is as:

```
$scope.open = function ($timeout, $log, parameter1) {

           var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
                resolve: {
                    items: function ($http) {
                        return "loadind data...";
                    }
                }
            });

            modalInstance.opened.then(function($timeout, $log) {
                $scope.loadData(modalInstance,$timeout, $log);
            }, function() {
                $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            });

            $scope.loadData = function(aModalInstance, $timeout, $log) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    aModalInstance.setItems("data loaded...");
                }, 3000);
            };

    };

        var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {
            $scope.items = items;

            $uibModalInstance.setItems = function(theData) {
                $scope.items = theData;
            };

            $scope.ok = function() {
                $uibModalInstance.close('close');
            };
            $scope.cancel = function() {
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        };
    });
```

Cant figure out why $timeout is not resolved, is it something related to parameter passing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include $timeout as a dependency in your controller.

Not only that $log and $http also needs to be included.

This statement in your uibModal:

```
    resolve: {
            items: function ($http) {
                return "loadind data...";
            }
        }
```

The $scope.items = items will just assign the string "loading data..." to it. I do not know the reason you are passing this to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

You need to inject $timeount,$http and $log in your Controller

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var testCtrl = function($scope, $modal, $timeout, $log,$http) {
$scope.open = function() {
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'testContent.html',
  controller: testCtrl,
  resolve: {
    mydata: function() {
      return "Loading...";
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You found the solutions in other answers. Now you need to have a look inside different methods of [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

> DI is pervasive throughout Angular. You can use it when defining
>   components or when providing run and config blocks for a module.
>
> Components such as services, directives, filters, and animations are
>   defined by an injectable factory method or constructor function. These
>   components can be injected with "service" and "value" components as
>   dependencies.
>
> Controllers are defined by a constructor function, which can be
>   injected with any of the "service" and "value" components as
>   dependencies, but they can also be provided with special dependencies.
>   See Controllers below for a list of these special dependencies.
>
> The run method accepts a function, which can be injected with
>   "service", "value" and "constant" components as dependencies. Note
>   that you cannot inject "providers" into run blocks.
>
> The config method accepts a function, which can be injected with
>   "provider" and "constant" components as dependencies. Note that you
>   cannot inject "service" or "value" components into configuration.